# Exact Process of Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: android, bluetooth, system, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been using Bluetooth Low energy to connect to a sensor. I would like to know the exact process by which connection and data transfer rates happen.

Could somebody verify that I have this process correct, or if not, please tell me where I am going wrong.

**ATT** - The framework for managing BLE connection

**GATT** - The process where either the server or client can request and accept pull requests, and the process with which data is stored from ATT

**GAP** - The data transfer back from the server to the client *OR* is it what establishes and manages connections between devices

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Gap** (Generic access protocol) is responsible for creating and managing connections. This includes start advertising, start scanning, create connection, updated connection parameters and establishing encrypted connections.

**Att** (Attribute protocol) is the attribute protocol. It defines the database that you query with the GATT client over a link. Attributes in BLE has a UUID defining the type of data stored, a handle and a value. Att also takes care of linking attributes together (a service attribute has a set of characteristics linked to it. A characteristic has a set of descriptors linked to it...)

**Gatt** (Generic Attribute profile) runs on top of the **Att**. A connected device can query the remote GATT server using it's local GATT client to retrieve the ATT attributes.

Hope that clarifies it a bit for you! Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) for instance